# How to rewrite an iframe multiple times with a script that declares a constant

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm writing an in-browser HTML editor where users write HTML code that is sent (on every keystroke) to an iframe for preview purposes. This is the code I have now:

```
onCodeChange(html) {
  iframe.contentDocument.open();
  iframe.contentDocument.write(html);
  iframe.contentDocument.close();
}
```

The problem appears when users try to add `<script>` tags with a `const` in them:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      const a = 42;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When a user types in `... const a = 4 ...` everything is fine (initial declaration of `a` as `4`), but when they finish typing `... const a = 42 ...` (redeclaration of `a` as `42`), then an error is thrown:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared

I think that this happens because the JavaScript context remains the same even if the document is rewritten.

I have tried using `srcdoc`:

```
onCodeChange(html) {
  iframe.srcdoc = html;
}
```

It works, but causes the iframe to flicker (I imagine that it unloads and loads the iframe) and I don't want users to have seizures...

I'm currently thinking about having two iframes (one on top of the other), using `srcdoc`, and swapping their `z-index` on load. It's very weird, but could fix the flickering.

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your script with an IIFE every time you want to change the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      (function(){const a = 42;})();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```